# Problem with \quote and \raggedright in ModernCV

Tags: horizontal-alignment, moderncv

Having an issue with the \quote part of ModernCV.

```
\quote{\raggedright \lipsum[2]}
```

Whilst the above produces exactly what I'm after, any effort to replace

```
\lipsum[2]
```

with other text results in the text not aligning as I wish.

This confuses me since the regular quote is as follows

```
\quote{Text}
```

Thanks in advance

Also,
here is the full doc:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv/moderncv}   
\renewcommand*{\listitemsymbol}{\itemsep-2em \labelitemi~}
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}   
\moderncvcolor{blue}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages/pdfpages}
\usepackage{moderntimeline/moderntimeline}
\tlmaxdates{2005}{2016}   
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch/xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitem}{#3}{\small #3}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\makecvtitle{\quotewidth}{0.9\textwidth}{}{} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[url=false,
backend=biber,            
style=authoryear,
doi=false,  
isbn=false,
backref=false,
dashed=false,                                   
maxnames=99,    
sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{cvreferences.bib}
\input{biblatex_modifications/standard_modification.tex} 
\newcommand{\cvreferencecolumn}[2]{%
\cvitem[0.75em]{}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemmaincolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
}%
}
\newcommand{\cvreference}[8]{%
\textbf{#1}\newline% Name
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{\href{mailto:#6}{\nolinkurl{#6}}}\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7\newline}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{}{\mobilephonesymbol~#8}}
\name{Name}{Name}
\address{Address}{Address}
\phone[mobile]{+00000000000}           
\email{mail@mail.com}              
\quote{\raggedright Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text }
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Apologies - hopefully now okay?

Comment: I should have been clearer on what a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is. If you can reproduce the same problem after removing a section of code, remove it. Repeat the process until the smallest number of lines remain. That will make it much easier for others to assist.

Comment: Is this suitable?

Comment: It's much closer, at least. I suspect more lines can be removed (pdfpages, biblatex, etc.). And it'll be much easier to read if you replace the '>' quoting you did with the 4-space indent you used on the earlier lines of code.

Comment: @DrDe: Now I don't see the problem...

Comment: @Werner Where the numerous "text"'s have been added, the block of text does not get aligned as it does when it is replaced with \quote{\raggedright \lipsum[2]}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

and place a `\lipsum`, it inherently adds `\par` at the end of the *Lorem Ipsum*. This `\par` forces the setting of a paragraph in whichever paragraph alignment has been set. As such,

```
\quote{\raggedright \lipsum[2]}
```

will set in a `\raggedright` fashion. However, using

```
\quote{\raggedright <some lengthy text>}
```

may not set it in `\raggedright` if there is no forced `\par` initiated. If you had used `\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}` instead, you may have experienced similar problems. To guarantee this, use one should use

```
\quote{\raggedright <some lengthy text>\endgraf}
```

The use of `\endgraf` circumvents the current non-`\long` definition of `\quote`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\makecvtitle}
{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}    
{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\raggedright\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}%
{}{}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\makecvtitle{\quotewidth}{0.9\textwidth}{}{}      %% this should be done here (after removing \centering)
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv/moderncv}
\renewcommand*{\listitemsymbol}{\itemsep-2em \labelitemi~}
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages/pdfpages}
\usepackage{moderntimeline/moderntimeline}
\tlmaxdates{2005}{2016}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\makecvtitle}
{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}    
{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\raggedright\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}%
{}{}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\makecvtitle{\quotewidth}{0.9\textwidth}{}{}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\name{Name}{Name}
\address{Address}{Address}
\phone[mobile]{+00000000000}
\email{mail@mail.com}
\quote{Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text Text text text }
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember to patch `\makecvtitle` for `\quotewidth` after you have removed `\centering` and added `\raggedright`.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy, actually. The `\quote` command simply stores the text in `\@quote`; when this text is printed it is passed as argument to `\quotestyle`, which is defined by default as

```
\newcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont#1}}
```

So all you need is to redefine this macro as

```
\renewcommand{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\raggedright#1\par}}
```

and your quote will be ragged right:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}   
\renewcommand*{\listitemsymbol}{\itemsep-2em \labelitemi~}
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}   
\moderncvcolor{blue}  

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\raggedright #1\par}}

\name{Name}{Name}
\address{Address}{Address}
\phone[mobile]{+00000000000}
\email{mail@mail.com}

\quote{\lipsum*[2]}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

(I've removed the inessential parts.)

[image]