# Indentation not restored after \quote{}

Tags: indentation, quoting

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
This is the first quote:
\quote{\lipsum[1]}
This sentence and the following quote should not be inside the first quote:
\quote{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

After the first quote, the quote indentation should end and go back to normal, but instead, the following paragraph continues at the same indentation as the first quote. The second quote hence gets double indentation.

Why is this the case, is it regular behaviour and how can I prevent it?

Comment: `\quote` is not a command with argument: correct is `\begin{quote}text\end{quote}`

Comment: Isn't quote an environment, i.e. `\begin{quote}\lipsum[2]\end{quote}`

Comment: The `moderncv` class, unfortunately, defines `\quote` as a command with argument. But it's not so in the standard classes, in Koma classes and `memoir`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only class I know that defines `\quote` as a command with argument is `moderncv` (see [Problem with \quote and \raggedright in ModernCV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227560/problem-with-quote-and-raggedright-in-moderncv) for an example).

All other classes I know define a `quote` *environment*. As a consequence, the command `\quote` is defined, but it should never be used in a document (unless it's in the `moderncv` class, of course).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

This is the first quote:
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
This sentence and the following quote should not be inside the first quote:
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

---

What happens in your example? When TeX sees `\begin{quote}`, it issues `\begingroup` that acts as a scope for the following setup declarations, such as wider margins, spacing between paragraphs and so on; after opening the group, the command `\quote` is issued, which indeed does the setup.

When, later, `\end{quote}` is found, a command `\endgroup` is issued, that ends the scope and reverts parameters to their previous values. Since you don't have a scope, such setup continues forever.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry if this isn’t the right place, but: For short quotes, should I use \enquote{...} instead of \begin{quote}...\end{quote}?

Comment: @Philipp Usage of `\enquote` is up to you. This command (with argument) is handy because it can decide about in line or displayed quotes, so it's a bit different from the `quote` environment.